# How to disable pasting words into a number-only edit control?

Tags: c, winapi, dialog, notepad, editcontrol

I am writing in C WinAPI a 'Go To Line' dialog of the notepad. I created a number only edit control. But I can still paste words into the edit control! The dialog in the windows notepad does stop this kind of pasting. So how can I do the same thing as it in the notepad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass the edit control, and when WM_PASTE is received:

```
OpenClipboard
GetClipboardData
GlobalLock
```

Now use the returned pointer from GlobalLock to check for non numeric characters.  If a non number is found, inform user then:

```
GlobalUnlock
CloseClipboard
```

and return 0 from the callback to prevent pasting the data into the edit control.

If it is all numbers, then `GlobalUnlock` and `CLoseClipboard` and pass message on with `CallWindowProc` to allow paste.

Comment: That *IS* the way to do it, using the Windows API.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for ES_NUMBER (which is what I presume you're using) says:

> Allows only digits to be entered into the edit control. Note that, even with this set, it is still possible to paste non-digits into the edit control.

To prevent pasting non-digits, you'll need to scan through the data in the clipboard and prevent pasting if it contains a non-digit.